# Unable to import stargazer ("ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stargazer')

Tags: python, pycharm, stargazer

After installing [stargazer](https://pypi.org/project/stargazer/), I am unable to import it.

I am using Pycharm 2020.1. I have tried installing stargazer (via pip) in both the local environment and directly in Terminal.

My specific code is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import statsmodels.api as sm
from stargazer.stargazer import Stargazer
```

where the last line returns the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 5, in <module>
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE with Anaconda plugin.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stargazer'
```

stargazer appears installed (from 'pip list'):

```
...
sklearn                                0.0    
stargazer                              0.0.4  
...
```

Would appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: Quick questions: 1) In PyCharm, is the import statement the same color as your other imports? 2) Are you working in a virtual environment?

Comment: Hi Ben - on 1) Yes, all "import"s are in orange and 2) Yes I am. Thanks.

Comment: Don't know if this means anything, especially since colors are configurable in PyCharm but, for me, my imports are in a combination of black & blue. blue for keywords and black for the modules and methods (just like your code shows above). I'm not familiar with how anaconda works but, given the error message, I wonder if the problem is with it, not with stargazer. Wish I had more to offer.

Comment: Appreciate it regardless. I tried 'conda install stargazer' - which does not work, so that could be the problem. Still odd it shows up in the list of installed packages.

Comment: :) Not sure if you've done this or if conda supersedes this capability but could you try just adding it as a package through your regular PyCharm preferences? (i.e. as though you don't have anaconda at all)

Comment: Good thought. Interestingly it is not listed as available for import through that mode, which I guess might be the issue. perplexing though, not sure what the incompatibility would be,